# vba how to optimize macro for many columns

Tags: vba

I want to write a macro to Count rows in columns conditionally, I have about 30 columns, i would like to have one macro for all  possible columns. I write a macro for the one columns, but dont know how to optimize them. 
My macro for the first column (110_1.1) is below. And I Need to write a macro for the next columns "120_1.2", "130_1.3", ... and so on until "810_8.1" and hence  Sheets("Element_errors").Cells(i, j) should take values "err120","err130",.."err810", and j=1..30 for every column. 
And Problem is also that all columns dont go one after another.

```
 Sub Element110_error()
    Dim zelle As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim posMonitoring As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim intLastRow As Integer

    With Sheets("ICS Table")
     intLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set zelle = .Cells.Find("110_1.1", lookat:=xlPart)

    If zelle Is Nothing Then
        For i = 2 To intLastRow
            Sheets("Element_errors").Cells(i, 1).Value = "no data"
        Next i
    Else
        posMonitoring = zelle.Column

        For i = 2 To intLastRow
            If .Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value < 1 Or .Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value > 10 Then
                Sheets("Element_errors").Cells(i, 1) = "err110"
            Else
                Sheets("Element_errors").Cells(i, 1) = "no"
            End If
        Next i


      End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: by you pattern I count 71 number sequences to test.  But you only have 30 columns?

Comment: do you want 71 columns of output?

Comment: i dont Need 71 columns , i have only 32 columns. in ideal Situation it would be great to have macro which finds only colomns which exist and give Output for them. However the numbers and names of the columns can be different

Comment: One more difficulties, some columns have normal Format of the data, from 0 to 12, while others in the Format like "300 - 349 (6)" and in this case only 6, is important for us. Is it possible to introduce additional condition, such as if length of the cell is longer than 4 sign, then look at the second number from the right?

Answer (score 1):

this will iterate each pattern and output on column for each:

```
Sub Element110_error()
    Dim zelle As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim posMonitoring As Integer
    Dim j As Long
    Dim intLastRow As Integer
    k = 0
    With Sheets("ICS Table")
        intLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 11 To 81
            Dim fnd As String
            fnd = j & "0_" & Left(j, 1) & "." & Right(j, 1)
            Set zelle = .Cells.Find(fnd, lookat:=xlPart)
            Sheets("Element_errors").Cells(1, j - 10).Value = fnd
            If zelle Is Nothing Then
                For i = 2 To intLastRow
                    Sheets("Element_errors").Cells(i, j - 10).Value = "no data"
                Next i
            Else
                posMonitoring = zelle.Column
                For i = 2 To intLastRow
                    If .Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value < 1 Or .Cells(i, posMonitoring).Value > 10 Then
                        Sheets("Element_errors").Cells(i, j - 10) = "err" & j & "0"
                    Else
                        Sheets("Element_errors").Cells(i, j - 10) = "no"
                    End If
                Next i


            End If
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```